# Django self-referential model as a many-to-many inline tree in the admin site

Tags: django, django-admin, django-forms

Suppose I have the following models in `models.py`:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self', null=True, blank=True)

class Item(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    categories = models.ManyToManyField(Category, related_name='categories')

class Membership(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item)
    date_assigned = models.DateField()
```

And, as documented in [Working with many-to-many intermediary models](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#working-with-many-to-many-intermediary-models), I have this in `admin.py`:

```
class MembershipInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Membership
    extra = 3

class CategoryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = (MembershipInline,)

class ItemAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = (MembershipInline,)
```

When creating an `Item` in the admin site, category inline forms are indeed rendered, but as mere `<select>` widgets, which is somewhat cumbersome, as each category is shown at the same level.

How could I get these rendered as trees? I don't need something very fancy and some indentation within the select would be just fine.

I tried with `django-mptt` and `django-treebeard`, but they don't seem to have the inline intermediary many-to-many model case covered.

Answer (score 2):

If you register the Item model with mptt. You can overwrite the unicode method:

```
class Item(models.Model):

    ...  

    def __unicode__(self):
         return '%s%s' % ('  ' * self.level, super(MarkerCategory, self).__unicode__())
```

If you want a cleaner solution, you should overwrite the form, and change the widget and to do this logic in this specific widget.

Comment: That's a hopeful idea, but browsers don't seem to honor those leading spaces when rendering the `<select>`, so `<option>   Foo</option>` shows just like `<option>Foo</option>`.

Comment: Did you try '- ' instead of '  '?

Answer (score 0):

I hate when browsers are "smart".

```
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe

...

class Item(models.Model):

    ...  

    def __unicode__(self):
         return mark_safe('%s%s' % ('&nbsp;' * 4 * self.level,
                          super(Item, self).__unicode__()))
```

But I recomend that this logic is in a specify widget